# Automatic https when using caddy for domain and ip address together

Tags: caddy

I am trying to access my website using both its domain name and static ip address via https protocol.

When I use just domain it works as expected, but when I add ip address as following:

```
my.domain.com {
  respond "Hello from domain"
}

10.20.30.40 {
    tls internal
    respond "Hello"
}
```

it does not work. Moreover if I use `tls internal` for different port:

```
my.domain.com {
  respond "Hello from domain"
}

:8080 {    <----------- Here I use port
    tls internal   <------------- and tls internal
    respond "Hello"
}
```

accessing by domain name in browser now warns that certs are not publicly trusted. I assume that `tls internal` in second block affected first block. Is it right? Why so?

Anyway, my main question is how to access my website both via domain name and ip address even if I need to use different ports with caddy over https. I know, that for some historical reason ip addresses cannot have publicly trusted certs so it is ok if ip address will use self signed certs.

pls help!

Caddy version: v2.3.0